# html table to excel not showing pound currency symbols

Tags: javascript, excel

I am creating an Excel file using an HTML table. Everything worked fine but I am having a hard time to display pound sign in the Excel. Even though I put a pound sign, it's not shown in the Excel.

Code:

```
html = escape(table_html);

//in my server i do this
echo "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64," . base64_encode($html);
//then back in the client

var $a = $("<a>");
$a.attr("href", data);
$("body").append($a);
$a.attr("download", "report.xls");
$a[0].click();
$a.remove();
```

[image: html table currency]

[image: excel currency]

Comment: If it is html to excel, why not use the html-entity `&pound;` for the pound character?

Comment: i did it was not showing

Answer (score 0):

Try using an html entity (`&pound;`) or numeric code (`&#163`) in place of the actual symbol. You did not include an HTML snippet so I can't think of anything else to suggest other than that. I have seen in other threads people having trouble getting base64 encoding to work on special characters. The pound symbol seems like it should work fine but I would try using the entity and numeric codes then come back and report if that worked or not.

Comment: it worked i think the problem was because of this line 
      html = escape(table_html);
when i use this instead
     html = encodeURIComponent($.trim($(".report_table").html()));
it worked